# Is it possible to create a Dynamic tree structure using the ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, c#-4.0, expandoobject

at the moment I am using the ExpandoObject to dynamically store firstname and surname.

e.g.

```
   // Create Expando object for testing
   dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();

   // Dynamically add the fields to the expando            
   ((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee).Add("FirstName", "John");
   ((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee).Add("Surname", "Smith");
```

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically store the fields into a tree structure so that i could have the parent field called Name, and then two child fields called Firstname and Surname. Ideally this could potentially be expanded to included more sub levels. I've done some psudo code below to demonstrate ideally how I would like it to work. (of course this code currently causes errors)

```
// Create Expando object for testing
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();

// Dynamically add the Name
((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee).Add("Name", "");

//Dynamically add the firstname and surname to employee.Name
((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee.Name).Add("FirstName", "John");
((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee.Name).Add("Surname", "Smith");
```

Comment: Expando? Is that some Harry Potter spell? +1 for interesting question

Comment: @sehe, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Comment: @George: Yeah, I'm google-certified since 2003

Comment: @sehe, Thought you'd never heard of it before and would appreciate a link. nm

Comment: @George: I _had_ never heard of it. It's a good find, that's why I expressed my surprise. Sorry if I sometimes get carried away too much on an informational site like SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What stops you from doing

```
 dynamic parent = new ExpandoObject();
 parent.Nick = "Dad";
 parent.Name = new ExpandoObject();
 parent.Name.FirstName = "John";
 parent.Name.MiddleName = "Tweeds";
 parent.Name.SurName = "Doe";

 parent.Spouse = new ExpandoObject();
 parent.Spouse.Nick = "Sweety";
 parent.Children = new [] {
     new ExpandoObject(),
     new ExpandoObject()
 };
 parent.Children[0].Nick = "P-J";
 parent.Children[0].Name = "Pete-Jay";
 parent.Children[1].Nick = "Tammie";
 parent.Children[1].Name = "Tamara";
```

Or similar? You wouldn't exactly get tree traversal for free, but that's basically a given when not using strongtypes nodes

**Update**; I just compiled and ran this using Mono C# compiler on Windows XP. Not even having MS.NET 4.0 installed :)

Comment: Yeah, that is an option but as its quite new i was wondering if anyone had done anything interesting with it around tree/folder views. thanks for answer

Comment: tree/folder views? that wasn't part of your question as I read it

Comment: True, i just mentioned it as i was looking into expanding it to included more sub levels in my post similar to a tree view.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Open source [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey#dynamitey-) (can be install via nuget, and is a Portable Class Library), you can make expandoobject graphs like this:

```
  using Dynamitey.DynamicObjects;
  ...

  dynamic New = Builder.New<ExpandoObject>();

  var person = New.Person(
      Name: New.Name(FirstName:"John", SurName:"Smith")
  );
```

You can also take a bunch of nested `IDictionary<string,object>` and make them act like a dynamic object with nested dynamic object properties by using:

```
using Dynamitey.DynamicObjects.Dictionary = DynamicDict;
...

dynamic obj = new DynamicDict(nestedDictionaries);
```